# Shutdown issues with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS my system doesn't shutdown. That is, after clicking on the shutdown button or issuing the , it gets stuck where we have the ubuntu logo. So I am obliged to hold the shutdown button. Any tips on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

try in terminal

`sudo shutdown now -P`

or you can login to **tty** by `Ctrl+Alt+F1` then `sudo shutdown now -P`